# Lightning Components: is there a way to render a Flexipage inside an other Lightning Component yet? Or roadmap? Or never?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, flexipages

As the title says, I want to use an entire Flexipage as a component itself (I bet that behind the scenes a Flexipage actually is one) inside an other Lightning Component as a subcomponent.

- Is that possible yet?
- Might it be possible in the future?
- Or better prepare that it won't come anytime soon or at all?

Futurelooking plus safeharbor hints are very welcome, too.

Comment: You won the bet but, Salesforce blackbox won't open!

Comment: @Ashwani that's too sad. I would really like to use the App Builder to layout the body of my own stuff. Unfortunately this road seems blocked right now but I'm still trying to figure a workaround or even a hack if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a flexipage is actually a Lightning component (*flexipage:page*) and a very powerful one. I've asked the product manager for Lightning Pages to comment here on roadmap plans for access="global"ing it. Somewhat ironically I was the first to ask for this awhile back - totally get the power of this capability.

Answer (score 3):

At this point, it is not possible to utilize Lightning Pages (Flexipages) as a programmatic building block for use in your own components.

Ultimately, it's something we'd like to do eventually since it would open up a wide range of options for customization of your apps.

Our current priority for Lightning Pages and App Builder is customization of Salesforce1 and Lightning Experience so I don't anticipate being able to support this type of use case in the next few releases.

As an alternative, as long as your app runs inside of Lightning Experience, you can use our capabilities combined with your custom components, objects, and logic to deliver a great experience that can be further customized by your subscribers.

Comment: Hi Eric, the need for this in the end is to nest "designed" content. With "designed" I mean stuff designed with App Builder. What currently seems to be possible (Spring'17) is not enough. Nice would be a way to put designs inside designs. Also a way to create custom flexi-layouts, instead of providing more and more pre-made layouts like 3-columns (spring'17). We would prefer a more flexible approach, whit control of width, height, proportions, collapsability. Globalizing flexipage:page and let us wrap it by a few lines of own code would do almost all it. As Doug said: it would be very powerful

Comment: Understood and it is on the plan, just further out. In the nearer term, we are planning to allow the creation of custom Lightning Page templates so that you can specify the number of regions and how they are displayed on the page.

Comment: Sounds great: Custom Lightning Page templates would definitely be very helpful, too. Any safeharbour-release-ETA on them yet?

Comment: We are planning to have initial support in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

It's been three years  and ten releases since this question was posted, and  still no signs of flexipages being exposed as first-class objects. I frankly don't understand what is meant by the answer which says to "use our capabilities combined with your custom components, objects, and logic to deliver a great experience that can be further customized by your subscribers." How can they customize layouts that are meant to be parts of composed pages?

The answer to the question, then, is that to accomplish this you would need to write your own component to display a flexipage, which actually might not be that horribly difficult.

Of course, you are then still left with no ability to customize, wrap, or curate the app building (page composition) experience--I mean AppBuilder exposed as a component itself-- so there's no way to personalize this for your own products purposes. Maybe in version 92.

Comment: I do agree Salesforce should provide more. My guess is, that nesting AppBuilder-flexipage might lead into possible perfomance issues or complexities, we are not aware of. Or they just have different priorities. It would be nice, if Salesforce could share more insights into Lightning roadmaps. Or maybe there are more infos out and someone could point us there? I also agree, that the given answer you mentioned is not very helpful. I was aware of this "use our capabilities combined with your custom components, objects, and logic to deliver a great experience that can be further customized by..."

Comment: `flexipage:page` seems to sort of work, with the `flexiPageDeveloperName` attribute, but so far I haven't figured out how to pass in the record ID, and I don't know what problems will arise from doing this, whether or not it's even OK to use this undocumented feature, whether it will work in a managed package, and what the implications of `access="global"` are.